# Unable to override SSR styling of styled components from packages

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, styled-components

I am working on a project where we make use of Styled Components with NextJS for server side rendering. We use a private package which we include in multiple custom projects. This private package contains styling, but in some projects we want to override the styling with our custom styling as can be seen in the code below. It seems like it has something to do with the component selector `${H1}`  not being able to find the actual H1 component. Why is this happening?

**Code in private package:**

```
const baseHeading = css`
    font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.sec};
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: bold;
`;
export const H1Styles = css`
    font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.content.headings.h1.b1};
    text-transform: uppercase;

    @media screen and (min-width: ${size.min.b4}) {
        font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.content.headings.h1.b4};
    }
`;
export const H1 = styled.h1`
    ${baseHeading};
    ${H1Styles};
`;
```

**Code in custom component:**

```
import { H1 } from '@testproject/testproject-core-ui'
....
<section className={className}>
    <FooterBrandingInner>
        <H1>
            <span>{params.LeftColumnTitleRow1}</span>
            <span>{params.LeftColumnTitleRow2}</span>
        </H1>
        ....

const FooterBrandingInner = styled.div`
    ${H1} {
        font-size: 3.8rem;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    ....
```

**Code in _document.tsx**

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx: any) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
    try {
        ctx.renderPage = () =>
            originalRenderPage({
                enhanceApp: (App: any) => (props: any) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
            });

        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
        return {
            ...initialProps,
            styles: (
                <>
                    {initialProps.styles}
                    {sheet.getStyleElement()}
                </>
            ),
        };
    } finally {
        sheet.seal();
    }
}
```

**Code in .babelrc**

```
[
    "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    {
        "ssr": true,
        "displayName": true,
        "preprocess": false
    }
]
```

### Expected Behavior

I would expect to see the H1 without 'text-transform: uppercase' when server side rendering.

### Actual Behavior

When we visit a page with the custom styling which is defined in our custom class, we will not see it while server side rendering. We do see it when we are not server side rendering. We do sometimes see a flash of the custom styling and it seems that the wrong ClassNames are being used on the component.